# Share Devise session cookie between two Rails apps of different versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to share a Devise session cookie for authentication purposes between two Rails apps on the same TLD but living on different subdomains. One app is v4.2.11.1, and the other is v6.0.3.2. I want to login on the Rails 4 app, and access the authenticated user info in the Rails 6 app. The session cookie is set fine when logging in on the Rails 4 app, but it seems to get completely wiped out/reset when trying to access it in the Rails 6 app.

- The session store cookie domain is set correctly for both apps, e.g. `.example.com`.
- The session store `tld_length` is set to `2` in both apps.
- The cookies serializer is set to `:marshal` in both apps.
- I'm using the same `secret_key_base` in both apps. In the Rails 4 app, it is set via the `ENV['SECRET_KEY_BASE']` env var. In the Rails 6 app, it's set via Rails credentials, e.g. `config/credentials/<env>.yml.enc`.
- `Devise.secret_key` is the same in both apps.
- I'm using the same Devise gem version and initializers in both apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be other things going on in your specific case, but it is worth nothing that there have been two backward-incompatible changes to session cookies since Rails 4 that you'll need to look at.

1. There was a change in Rails 5.2 to embed expiry information into encrypted cookies. From the [upgrade guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#expiry-in-signed-or-encrypted-cookie-is-now-embedded-in-the-cookies-values):

> To improve security, Rails now embeds the expiry information also in
> encrypted or signed cookies value.
>
> This new embed information make those cookies incompatible with
> versions of Rails older than 5.2.
>
> If you require your cookies to be read by 5.1 and older, or you are
> still validating your 5.2 deploy and want to allow you to rollback set
> `Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.use_authenticated_cookie_encryption`
> to `false`.

2. Rails 6.0 has a change to embed purpose in encrypted cookies. From
   the [upgrade
   guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#purpose-in-signed-or-encrypted-cookie-is-now-embedded-within-cookies):

> To improve security, Rails embeds the purpose information in encrypted
> or signed cookies value. Rails can then thwart attacks that attempt to
> copy the signed/encrypted value of a cookie and use it as the value of
> another cookie.
>
> This new embed information make those cookies incompatible with
> versions of Rails older than 6.0.
>
> If you require your cookies to be read by Rails 5.2 and older, or you
> are still validating your 6.0 deploy and want to be able to rollback
> set `Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.use_cookies_with_metadata`
> to `false`.